# CUDA/CUBLAS Matrix-Vector Multiplication

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, cuda, cublas

I previously posted a question regarding matrix-vector multiplication in CUDA and about writing my own kernel. After doing this, I decided to implement my problem using CUBLAS as suggested by some users (thanks @Robert Crovella ) on SO in the hopes of achieving higher performance (my project is performance driven).

Just to clarify: I want to multiply a NxN matrix with a 1xN vector.

I've been looking at the code pasted below for a couple of days now and I cant figure out why the multiplication is giving me an incorrect result. I fear that i am causing problems by using < vector > arrays (this is part of a much larger system that uses these data types). I don't mean to use this thread as a debugging tool but I think this will also be helpful to other users trying to achieve this as I have not come across a particularly comprehensive source on the internet for my particular problem (and for the cublas v2 API). Thanks in advance!

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <time.h>

//#include "timenow.cu"

// error check macros
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

// for CUBLAS V2 API
#define cublasCheckErrors(fn) \
    do { \
        cublasStatus_t __err = fn; \
        if (__err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal cublas error: %d (at %s:%d)\n", \
                (int)(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

// random data filler
void fillvector(float *data, int N){
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        data[i] = float(rand() % 10);
    }
}

//printer
void printer(bool printOut, float *data, int N){
    if(printOut == true){
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%2.1f ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(){

bool printOut = true;

int N;
std::cout << "Enter N: " ;
std::cin >> N;

std::vector<float> x0;
x0.resize(N);

std::vector<float> p;
p.resize(N*N);

// matrix A
std::vector<float> A[N];
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        A[i].resize(N);
    fillvector(A[i].data(), N);
    printer(printOut, A[i].data(), N);
}
printf("\n");
fillvector(x0.data(), N);
printer(printOut, x0.data(), N);

printf("\nStarting CUDA computation...");
///double startTime = timenow();

// device pointers
float *d_A, *d_p, *d_b, *d_x0, *d_v, *d_temp;

cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, N*N*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_temp, N*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_x0, N*sizeof(float));
cudaCheckErrors("cuda malloc fail");

// might need to flatten A...
cublasSetVector(N, sizeof(float), &x0, 1, d_x0, 1);
//daMemcpy(d_x0, &x0, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cublasSetMatrix(N, N, sizeof(float), &A, N, d_A, N);
cudaCheckErrors("cuda memcpy of A or x0 fail");

float *temp;
temp = (float *)malloc(N*sizeof(temp));

cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasCheckErrors(cublasCreate(&handle));

float alpha = 1.0f;
float beta = 0.0f;
cublasCheckErrors(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, N, &alpha, d_A, N, d_x0, 1, &beta, d_temp, 1));

cublasGetVector(N, sizeof(float), &temp, 1, d_temp, 1);
//cudaMemcpy(temp, d_temp, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaCheckErrors("returning to host failed");

printf("\n");
printer(printOut, temp, N);

/*alpha = -1.0;
cublasSaxpy(handle, N, &alpha, d_temp, 1, d_v, 1);
cublasGetVector(N, sizeof(float) * N, d_v, 1, &v, 1);
printf("\n");
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    printf("%2.1f ",v[i]);
}*/

printf("\nFinished CUDA computations...");
//double endTime = timenow();

//double timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
//printf("\nRuntime: %2.3f seconds \n", timeDiff);

cudaFree(d_temp);
cudaFree(d_A);
cudaFree(d_p);
cudaFree(d_x0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  If it is that your multiplication is giving an incorrect result, please give us an idea of the results you are getting and the results you expect.  Also, you're not doing cublas error checking on your get/set matrix/vector calls.

Comment: Your program seems to allow any input.  When I input N=2, I get a cuda error message of invalid argument at your "returning to host failed" message.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi Robert, I would like to multiply a square matrix of NxN by vector of 1xN. N should be any size.

Comment: If I set N=5 say, i get the follow output returned for temp:
    Before: 0.0 2.0 3.0 7.0 5.0   After: 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -158953476882379259956604960768.0

Comment: Even if I pass N=5 to your code, it returns an error with the "returning to host failed"  message.  Is this the code you are running? Please paste in the actual program output when you run it, into the question (you can edit your question, don't try to put it in the comments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- We don't reference the first element of a vector this way:

  ```
  cublasSetVector(N, sizeof(float), &x0, 1, d_x0,
  ```

Instead you should do this:

```
cublasSetVector(N, sizeof(float), &(x0[0]), 1, d_x0, 1);
```

And likewise for your `SetMatrix` call referencing `A`:

```
cublasSetMatrix(N, N, sizeof(float), &(A[0]), N, d_A, N);
```

- Your `GetVector` call has 2 errors:

  ```
  cublasGetVector(N, sizeof(float), &temp, 1, d_temp, 1);
  ```

You have your `temp` and `d_temp` parameters [reversed](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasgetvector) (you are copying from device to host) and you should not take the address of `temp`: it is already a pointer.  So do this:

```
cublasGetVector(N, sizeof(float), d_temp, 1, temp, 1);
```

- You're not doing proper error checking on all cublas calls, such as your get/set matrix/vector calls. Use the same method you are using on other cublas calls for these also.
- You are creating `A` as an array of vectors.  This won't work with `cublasSetMatrix`.  Instead we need to create `A` as a flat vector, of sufficient size (N*N) to store the entire matrix.
- Finally, cublas expects the matrices it uses to be stored in column-major order.  If you pass C-style arrays in row-major order, you should use the transpose for that matrix in `cublasSgemv`:

  ```
  cublasCheckErrors(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, N, N, &alpha, d_A, N, d_x0, 1, &beta, d_temp, 1));
  ```

The following code has these various problems fixed:

```
$ cat t235.cu
#include <cuda.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <time.h>

//#include "timenow.cu"

// error check macros
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

// for CUBLAS V2 API
#define cublasCheckErrors(fn) \
    do { \
        cublasStatus_t __err = fn; \
        if (__err != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal cublas error: %d (at %s:%d)\n", \
                (int)(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

// random data filler
void fillvector(float *data, int N){
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        data[i] = float(rand() % 10);
    }
}

//printer
void printer(bool printOut, float *data, int N){
    if(printOut == true){
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%2.1f ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(){

bool printOut = true;

int N;
std::cout << "Enter N: " ;
std::cin >> N;

std::vector<float> x0;
x0.resize(N);

std::vector<float> p;
p.resize(N*N);

// matrix A
std::vector<float> A(N*N);
fillvector(A.data(), N*N);
for (int i=0; i< N; i++){
  printer(printOut, &(A[(i*N)]), N);
  printf("\n");}
fillvector(x0.data(), N);
printer(printOut, x0.data(), N);

printf("\nStarting CUDA computation...");
///double startTime = timenow();

// device pointers
float *d_A, *d_x0, *d_temp;

cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, N*N*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_temp, N*sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_x0, N*sizeof(float));
cudaCheckErrors("cuda malloc fail");

// might need to flatten A...
cublasCheckErrors(cublasSetVector(N, sizeof(float), &(x0[0]), 1, d_x0, 1));
//daMemcpy(d_x0, &x0, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cublasCheckErrors(cublasSetMatrix(N, N, sizeof(float), &(A[0]), N, d_A, N));
//cudaCheckErrors("cuda memcpy of A or x0 fail");

float *temp;
temp = (float *)malloc(N*sizeof(temp));

cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasCheckErrors(cublasCreate(&handle));

float alpha = 1.0f;
float beta = 0.0f;
cublasCheckErrors(cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, N, N, &alpha, d_A, N, d_x0, 1, &beta, d_temp, 1));

cublasCheckErrors(cublasGetVector(N, sizeof(float), d_temp, 1, temp, 1));
//cudaMemcpy(temp, d_temp, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
//cudaCheckErrors("returning to host failed");

printf("\n");
printer(printOut, temp, N);

/*alpha = -1.0;
cublasSaxpy(handle, N, &alpha, d_temp, 1, d_v, 1);
cublasGetVector(N, sizeof(float) * N, d_v, 1, &v, 1);
printf("\n");
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    printf("%2.1f ",v[i]);
}*/

printf("\nFinished CUDA computations...\n");
//double endTime = timenow();

//double timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
//printf("\nRuntime: %2.3f seconds \n", timeDiff);

cudaFree(d_temp);
cudaFree(d_A);
//cudaFree(d_p);
cudaFree(d_x0);

return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -O3 -o t235 t235.cu -lcublas
$ ./t235
Enter N: 5
3.0 6.0 7.0 5.0 3.0

5.0 6.0 2.0 9.0 1.0

2.0 7.0 0.0 9.0 3.0

6.0 0.0 6.0 2.0 6.0

1.0 8.0 7.0 9.0 2.0

0.0 2.0 3.0 7.0 5.0

Starting CUDA computation...
83.0 86.0 92.0 62.0 110.0

Finished CUDA computations...
$
```

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. The  points regarding how to specify/use arrays and their pointers are especially useful!

Comment: How would you say this fairs against a parallel cpu computation using say 6 cores? I ask because I'm not entirely convinced my timing module works correctly. I am looking at N about 1000.

Comment: I am also concerned about how much flattening the matrix A is going to affect performance? is there a trade-off in terms of the matrix manipulations after?

Comment: Your code may have to be re-written, but there's no reason it should be lower performance.

Comment: Hi Robert, is it possible to use cublasSgemv() with 2 flat matricies d_A and d_Q that are on the device, expect i want to multiply A[N x N] with a column from Q[N x (0.5N+1)] ?

Comment: You should probably post this as a new SO question.

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm still not quite sure as to why we use the cublasSetMatrix() function. Since were simply transferring a 1 dimensional array (ie the flattened matrix), can't we just use cublasSetVector() or even cudaMemcpy() ?

Comment: Yes, you can use either of those as well.

Comment: Is there a difference in terms of what they are used for? Does using cublasSetMatrix() mean I can avoid flattening the matrices? Otherwise, is there any point to them?

Comment: Yes, there are differences.  Perhaps you should read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublassetmatrix).  All 3 approaches expect single pointers, so flattening is still used in each case.  SetMatrix understands that the underlying data is a 2D matrix, and so allows you to do things like transfer a partial subset of the matrix, instead of the whole matrix, for example.  I can't cover all this in comments, please post new questions.  I don't intend to respond to any further new questions posed in this comment area.