# CUDA/CUBLAS: Accessing elements in an array

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, cuda, cublas

As a follow up to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516373/cuda-cublas-matrix-vector-multiplication), I am trying to implement the following loop, which is a matrix-vector multiplication where the vector is a column from the matrix Q, based on the loop iterator :

EDIT: Q cannot be populated before hand but is populated with the progression of iterator K.

```
for (unsigned K=0;K<N;K++){   // Number of iterations loop
    //... do some stuff
    for (unsigned i=0; i<N; i++){
        float sum = 0;
        for (unsigned j=0; j<N; j++){
            sum += A[j][i]*Q[j][K];
        }
        v[i] = sum;
    }
    //... do some stuff
    // populate next column of Q
}
```

Where the dimensions of the arrays are:

A [N x N]

Q [N x (0.5N + 1)]

This arrays have been flattened in order to use them with cublasSgemv(). My question is, is it possible to use cublasSgemv() by telling it where to start accessing d_Q, and what the increment of the elements are (since it is row-major C++):

EDIT: multiplied memoery access increment with sizeof(float). Still doesn't work as far as i can tell.

```
Niter = 0.5*N + 1;
for (unsigned K=0;K<N;K++){
    cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, N, N, &alpha, d_A, N, (d_Q + sizeof(float)*K*(Niter)), (Niter), &beta, d_v , 1);
}
```

I don't think Its possible to index d_Q like that as I am not getting any results

SOLVED: the solution by @RobertCrovella is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You are performing the scalar product between all the possible pairs `(a,q)`, where `a` is a column of `A` and `q` is a column of `Q`. Could you obtain the same result by a standard matrix-matrix multiplication between `A` transposed and `Q` by using `cublasSgemm`?

Comment: i only really want to use the single column from Q as the matrix is only populated at that column, and is subsequently populated in the global loop (K).

Comment: Why cannot you populate the matrix `Q` before the loops? In any case, this does not appear to be clear in your question. Perhaps you could consider editing it to be more precise about implementation constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to index through your flattened `Q` matrix the way you propose.  Your call to [Sgemv](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemv) should be as follows:

```
cublasSgemv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, N, N, &alpha, d_A, N, (d_Q + K), (Niter), &beta, (d_v+(K*Niter)) , 1);
```

The pointer to `Q` should point to the first element of the column in question, and since your matrix is row-major, this is just `d_Q + K` (using pointer arithmetic, not byte arithmetic).  `Niter` is the stride (in elements, not bytes) between successive elements of the column in question.  Note that your code as written would overwrite the results of one matrix-vector multiply with the next, since you are not indexing through `d_v` the output vector.  So I added some indexing on `d_v`.

As @JackOLantern points out, it should also be possible to do this in a single step without your loop, by calling [Sgemm](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm):

```
cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_T N, Niter,  N, &alpha, d_A, N, d_Q, (Niter), &beta, d_v, N);
```

If your code is not working the way you expect, please provide a complete, compilable example.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I do not intend to retain the matrix-vector multiply in d_v so indexing is not necessary. I will try this out. 
With respect to @JackOLantern 's proposal, this is not possible at this time as matrix Q is populated with the progression of the K loop.