# Multiple matrix-vector calls with CUBLAS

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I currently have to perform 128 independent sequential matrix-vector CUBLAS operations. All the matrices and vectors are different. Each independent matrix is stored right after the next in memory and the vectors are likewise stored contiguously in memory (all in row-major form).

A bit more context:
The matrices are (2048 X 8) and the vector is length 2048. The outputs are all **independent**. Because I have super matrices, I have the following:

```
matrix[(2048*128)x8]
vector[(2048*128)x1]
output[(8*128)x1]
```

With **cublasSgemv** I'm doing a transpose on the each mini matrix first and then adding (rather than replacing) the result into memory with:

```
cublasSgemv(*handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, Bdim, Adim, scale1, d_matrix + offset1, Bdim, d_vector + offset2, 1, scale2, out + offset3, 1);
```

I am making 128 such calls which I would like to do in **one**.

The profiler shows significant performance degradation from making these multiple calls. What is the best way to do multiple matrix-vector operations? Is there a way to batch them together into one fast call?

Are streams the best way to go or is there some way to make a call with relevant offsets (to index into my array of matrices and vectors)? The only other efficient option seemed to be to use a CUSPASE call and stick all the matrices on the diagonal.

NOTE: I'm not interested in getting the transposes or row/column major ordering in the gemv call correct for this particular question.

Comment: probably you should show some code.  Since you are doing multiple calls, you might want to transpose the matrix first (maybe with Sgeam), then call the Sgemv operations without having to specify CUBLAS_OP_T   Sounds like you're doing the same thing as what is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573099/cuda-cublas-accessing-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: Why do you need do transpose? result[8x1] = matrix[8x2048] * vector[2048x1] It seems nothing need to be transposed. what do you mean by `stored contiguously in memory`? how exactly do they stored?

Comment: Have a look at the cuBLAS library user guide. At Section 2.6, you will find how to use the batch functionality, which is a particular application of CUDA streams.

Comment: What do you mean by sequential? Does the result of one gemv operation affect the result of the next operation? Or are they independent of one another?

Comment: @Eric Each matrix is stored immediately after the previous one in memory; same for each vector. Sorry, the transpose *was* necessary - I hadn't reversed the dimensions to make that obvious in the question.

Comment: @talonmies All the gemv calls are *independent*.

Comment: @WillWilliams: So why not use a single gemm call instead? It would be really helpful if you could show some code. At this point I am not sure whether I have completely misunderstood your problem or you don't understand much about linear algebra.....

Comment: maybe you could edit your question to make it easier for others to understand and provide help.

Comment: for your 128 matrices, are they stored in row-major or column-major?

Comment: @WillWilliams But what do you mean that you would like to do all the matrix-vector multiplications in one? Because you would just like to avoid the overhead due to different kernel launches or because the involved matrices are actually submatrices of a unique matrix-vector product?

Comment: @JackOLantern  I would just like to avoid the overhead due to different kernel launches. There has to be a way to improve occupancy here.

Comment: @WillWilliams I do not like to insist, but have you considered using the batch possibility of cuBLAS? I do not have a direct experience with that, but I was considering using them in the past. I believe it should help you to achieve a concurrent execution of those independent matrix-vector products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

In fact you have to pay special attention to the r/c major ordering if your want to speed up your code in this case.

As shown in your revised question, you use row-major matrices. then you have a super-matrix A[(2048*128)x8] and a super vector V[(2048*128)x1]. And here I assume that you want a col-major matrix output[8x128] (can be seen as a super-vector [(8*128)x1]), where each col is the result of transpose( miniA[2048x8] ) * miniV[2048x1].

On the other hand, CUBLAS assumes that matrices are stored in column-major. So it may need some extra matrix transpose routines to change the ordering.

Since you need 128 independent [8x1] results, it should be able to calculate the result in **4** cuda API calls, which should be more efficient than your original **128** calls.

```
1. Row-major A[(2048*128)x8] can be seen as colum-major AA[8x(2048*128)]
   B[8x(2048*128)] = AA[8x(2048*128)] * diag( V[[(2048*128)x1]] )  by 1 dgmm()

2. C[(2048*128)x8] = transpose( B[8x(2048*128)] )                  by 1 geam()

3. Col-major C[(2048*128)x8] can be seen as col-major CC[2048x(8*128)]
   O[1x(8*128)] = ones[1x2048] * CC[2048x(8*128)]                  by 1 gemv()

4. Row vector O[1x(8*128)] can be seen as col-major matrix OO[128x8]
   output[8x128] = transpose( OO[128x8] )                          by 1 geam()
```

This col-major output[8x128] is what you want.

Since you need `adding` rather then `replacing`, you may need one more call to add the orginal values to `output`

Comment: What do you like to achieve with this solution?

Comment: @JackOLantern sorry, as you may noticed english is not my mother tone. your word is hard to understand.

Comment: I do not think this answer will match the poster question, see one of his last comments as well as his edited question.

Comment: @Eric "since you will add all the 128 mat-vec-mul results together" that would be nice but the outputs are independent

Comment: @JackOLantern when he said `adding (rather than replacing)`, I thought the result is out[8x1]. but then the Q changed again..

Comment: This looks like a great answer @Eric but I can't get the maths to work through: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=psABQE5W. The answer could also be improved by discussing the best way to create diagonal matrices on the fly (which would at least be one more kernel or cublas call).

Comment: @WillWilliams the key point is not about the math, but the store ording. My recipe is for row-major mat only, but matlab use column major. They will get different result when doing reshape(). So you won't be able to verify this recipe by matlab code. On the other hand, reshape() and diag() are concept representations. No cuda call is needed to achieve them. See doc of dgmm() for that.

Comment: @WillWilliams I made a mistake. Actually cublas always assume that the matrices are stored in col-major. I modified the recipe. It still need 4 cuda calls.

Comment: I still do not understand, how would 1 GEMV suffice for all 128 operations. Am assuming each result of the 128 operations is independent of the other.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a very quick launch of the `batchCUBLAS` SDK example. I have considered `128` independent runs for matrices of size `2048x8` and `8x1`. Here are the results on an NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M (compute capability 2.1) and on a Kepler K20c (compute capability 3.5).

For the NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M case, there is no relevant improvement for the "streamed" and "batched" versions against the "non-streamed" cuBLAS execution.

For the NVIDIA Kepler K20c, I have obtained

`sgemm`    1.87 GFlops (non-streamed);    3.08 GFlops (streamed);    6.58 GFlops (batched);

`dgemm`    1.00 GFlops (non-streamed);    1.43 GFlops (streamed);    6.67 GFlops (batched);

Streamed and batched cases seem to relevantly improve the non-streamed case for single precision.

**Disclaimers**

1. I'm not accounting for transposition, as you do;
2. The SDK example considers matrix-matrix multiplications, whereas you are needing matrix-vector multiplications; streaming is possible for gemv, but not batching.

I hope that those partial results could provide you with some useful information.